# Converting a list of lists of indices into a sparse matrix of ones and zeros

Tags: list-manipulation, sparse-arrays

I have data formatted like `{{a,b},{c,d},{e,f}}` where each entry is an integer. I need to turn this in to a sparse array with entries `{a,1}->1, {b,1}->1, {c,2}->1, ... {f,3}->1` and so on. In other words, if $x$ is an integer in the $j$th list, we need coordinate $(x,j)$ of the sparse matrix to be $1$.

How should I accomplish this?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: You might want to look up `IncidenceMatrix[]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
l = {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}};
Flatten[MapIndexed[{#1, #2[[1]]} -> 1 &, l, {2}], 1]

    (*{{a, 1} -> 1, {b, 1} -> 1, {c, 2} -> 1, {d, 2} -> 1, {e, 3} -> 
  1, {f, 3} -> 1}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}};
```

Using `ReplacePart`

```
Join @@ ReplacePart[list, {i_, j_} :> {list[[i, j]], i} -> 1]
```

{{a, 1} -> 1, {b, 1} -> 1, {c, 2} -> 1, {d, 2} -> 1, {e, 3} ->
1, {f, 3} -> 1}

Answer (score 2):

Another way is the following:

```
{{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}};
Table[i, {i, 1, First@Dimensions[%]}, {j, 1, Last@Dimensions[%]}]
Table[1, Total[Length /@ %%]]
%%% // Flatten
%%% // Flatten
Thread[{%%, %}]
Thread[% -> #] &@%%%%
```

> {{a, 1} -> 1, {b, 1} -> 1, {c, 2} -> 1, {d, 2} -> 1, {e, 3} ->
> 1, {f, 3} -> 1}

Answer (score 1):

Another way is the following:

```
l = {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}};

Flatten[Table[{l[[i, j]], i} -> 1, {i, Length[l]}, {j, Length[l[[i]]]}], 1]

(*{{a, 1} -> 1, {b, 1} -> 1, {c, 2} -> 1, {d, 2} -> 1, {e, 3} -> 1, {f, 3} -> 1}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
MapIndexed[Splice @ Thread[Tuples @ {##} -> 1] &] @ l
```

> ```
> {{a, 1} -> 1, {b, 1} -> 1,   
>  {c, 2} -> 1, {d, 2} -> 1,   
>  {e, 3} -> 1, {f, 3} -> 1}
> ```